# Sidebar allowing for double clicks of urls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a sidebar navigation in react js.

I am noticing that as an example, when I click Contact Us, I navigate to `localhost/contact-us`
If I click Contact Us again, I am navigated to the page `localhost/contact-us/contact-us`

How can I alter my code to adjust this so I cannot double click a URL, and only navigate to a page once? Want to avoid having users accidentally clicking a link twice, and navigating to an empty page

```
const sidebarNavItems = [
       {
            display: 'Home',
            to: '/'
        
        },
        {
            display: 'Blog',
            to: 'Blog/'
        },
        {
            display: 'Contact Us',
            to: 'contact-us/'
        },
        {
            display: 'Sign Up',
            to: 'sign-up/'
        },
        {
            display: 'Login',
            to: 'sign-in/'
        },
       
    ]

    const Sidebar = () => {
        const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
        const [stepHeight, setStepHeight] = useState(0);
        const sidebarRef = useRef();
        const indicatorRef = useRef();
        const location = useLocation();
    
        useEffect(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const sidebarItem = sidebarRef.current.querySelector('.sidebar__menu__item');
                indicatorRef.current.style.height = `${sidebarItem.clientHeight}px`;
                setStepHeight(sidebarItem.clientHeight);
            }, 50);
        }, []);

         // change active index
    useEffect(() => {
        const curPath = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
        const activeItem = sidebarNavItems.findIndex(item => item.section === curPath);
        setActiveIndex(curPath.length === 0 ? 0 : activeItem);
    }, [location]);
    

    return (
      <div className='sidebar'>
      <div className="sidebar__logo">
      <div><img src = {Logo} alt='Logo'className='Logo' /></div>
      </div>
      <div ref={sidebarRef} className="sidebar__menu">
          <div
              ref={indicatorRef}
              className="sidebar__menu__indicator"
              style={{
                  transform: `translateX(-50%) translateY(${activeIndex * stepHeight}px)`
              }}
          ></div>
          {
              sidebarNavItems.map((item, index) => (
                  <Link to={item.to} key={index}>
                      <div className={`sidebar__menu__item ${activeIndex === index ? 'active' : ''}`}>
                          <div className="sidebar__menu__item__icon">
                              {item.icon}
                          </div>
                          <div className="sidebar__menu__item__text">
                              {item.display}
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </Link>
              ))
          }
      </div>
  </div>);
};
    

export default Sidebar;
```

Here is sidebar CSS

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 20vw;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.sidebar__logo {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 5vh;
}
.sidebar__menu {
    position: relative;
}
.sidebar__menu__item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    place-content: flex-start;
    padding: 1rem 3rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #555;
    transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.sidebar__menu__item.active {
    color: #fff;
}
.sidebar__menu__item__icon {
    margin-right: 1rem;
}
.sidebar__menu__item__icon i {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
}
.sidebar__menu__indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #FD954E;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

EDIT:

Using first answer, it causes urls to still overlap. Example, if I click contact us, and then sign up, url is:
`http://localhost:3000/contact-us/sign-up/`

Router

```
function App() {
  return (

    <div className="App">
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<AppLayout />}/>
                    <Route index element={<Home />} />           
                     <Route path="/sign-in" element={<Login />} />
                     <Route path="/contact-us" element={<Contact />} />
            <Route path="/sign-up" element={<SignUp />} />
          </Routes>

</div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: It would help if you could create a reproducible example on either Code Sandbox, or JS Fiddle.

Comment: @VighneshRaut added CSS. HTML is included in code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try prefixing the path name with '/'.

For example, modify

```js
const sidebarNavItems = [
       {
            display: 'Home',
            to: '/'
        
        },
        {
            display: 'Blog',
            to: 'Blog/'
        },
        ...
    ]
```

to

```js
const sidebarNavItems = [
       {
            display: 'Home',
            to: '/'
        
        },
        {
            display: 'Blog',
            to: '/Blog/'
        },
        ...
    ]
```

The Code Sample :

[image: Edit TextField selectionStart]

Comment: See Edit. Still causing URLS to overlap

Comment: @KirkCode I try my solution again, but it worked fine for me, I make a sample for you.

Comment: Could it also be due to my router? I have just added to edit

Comment: Do you prefix all the path name with '/' ?

Comment: @KirkCode I edited the sample to simulate your router and it seems to work fine.